# Scrollview ambiguity

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout, xcode8, xib

[image]

I have a xib and it consists of one main default view and I have added two subviews under the main view, nameled: "RootView" and "scrollHolderView". I have pinned the "RootView" edges to main default view and given specific height. The edges of  "ScrollHolderView" is pinned to the "RootView" bottom. Inside the "ScrollHolderView" I have added scrollview (Content Scroll View) and inside the scroll view , one view (contentView) is added.

I followed the same steps as described in this link, but it is not scrolling. But when I remove constraints (i.e "Equal Widths" and "Equal Heights") between "contentView" and "scrollHolderView", it is scrolling but error is shown and the out is not as expected.

What's wrong here ?

I'm using Xcode 8.2.1 , XIB, iOS10.2

Comment: Post your question is proper format.

Comment: What's the exact error message in IB? Also helpful if you share the storyboard file.

Comment: Error is scrollview height and width ambiguity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per your comment "Error is scrollview height and width ambiguity" - this tells you exactly what you need to define. To resolve the error, Content View needs a a width and height in order to be scrollable.

Commonly it's equal width between the content view and the scroll view (no horizontal scrolling), and a height that's defined by the content inside the content view by constraining the bottom of the content view to the last element inside of it (or a fixed height).

If you still have trouble, post the storyboard file or xib.

Comment: Thanks Ben. I was doing everything perfectly, except I missed the constraining the bottom of the content view to the last element. It's fixed and working. Thanks again. Cheers !